# Не заносятся данные в базу данных, что делать

Tags: php

[image: таблица в базе данных]

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $passNumData = $_POST['passNumData'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $photo = $_POST['photo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];

    if ($password === $password_confirm) {

        $path = 'uploads/' . time() . $_FILES['photo']['name'];
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../' . $path)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ошибка при загрузке сообщения';
            header('Location: ../register.php');
        }

        $password = md5($password);

        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `shopper` (
            `shopperId`, `surname`, `name`, `lastname`, `passNumData`, `adress` `email`, `telephone`, `photo`, `password`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$surname', '$name', '$lastname', '$passNumData', '$adress', '$email', '$telephone', '$path', '$password')");

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Регистрация прошла успешно!';
        header('Location: ../index.php');


    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    }

?>
```

Comment: там обычно текст ошибки какой-то отображается.

Comment: недавно отвечал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1273539/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4?noredirect=1#comment2242383_1273539

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать конкретную ошибку по данному участку кода без полной структуры базы данных и примера отправленных данных, но вот что можна предпринять для решения данной проблемы:

1. Включить отображение всех ошибок. Для этого в начало файла после тега php добавьте следуйщий код:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

2. Вывести sql ошибку самому. Добавте после запроса:

```
   var_dump(mysqli_error($connect));
```

3. Еще можна протестировать запрос в phpmyadmin и посмотреть ошибку там. Код для вывода запроса:

```
   echo "INSERT INTO `shopper` (
            `shopperId`, `surname`, `name`, `lastname`, `passNumData`, `adress` `email`, `telephone`, `photo`, `password`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$surname', '$name', '$lastname', '$passNumData', '$adress', '$email', '$telephone', '$path', '$password')";
```

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь сохранить не валидные данные. Как вариант shopperId не может быть NULL. Ну и конечно будьте уверены что код вообще доходить до момента з запросом.

Также я вас советую ознакомится с темой SQL инъекций [https://habr.com/ru/post/130826/#:~:text=SQL](https://habr.com/ru/post/130826/#:%7E:text=SQL) а также добавить минимальную вадидацию.

Удачи